# SharePoint Installation suggestion required

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Planning to install SharePoint 2013,

- 1WFE,
- 1 App Ser,
- 1 Backend DB Server.

Could anyone suggest where to the installation?

Answer (score 2):

First, check the [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx) and make sure that your current environment match at least the minimum requirements.

Then check the installation steps at

- The Microsoft official article [Install and configure SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262957.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- or at [SharePoint 2013 - Step-By-Step Installation Guide](http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/page/install-sharepoint-2013.aspx)
- If you don't need to read and apply you can watch and apply this video [SharePoint 2013 Server Installation Step By Step Full](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u81RqLqWLC8)

**Note:**

- Make sure that there is no issue in the connectivity among the farm servers check [HOW TO CHECK SQL SERVER INSTANCE CONNECTIVITY FROM THE APPLICATION SERVER TO DATABASE SERVER FOR A SPECIFIC USER WITHOUT USING SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/28/check-sql-server-instance-connectivity/)
- Make sure that the required ports have been opened, and there is no issue with the firewall. check [CANNOT CONNECT TO DATABASE MASTER AT SQL SERVER AT SERVERNAME. THE DATABASE MIGHT NOT EXIST, OR THE CURRENT USER DOES NOT HAVE PERMISSION TO CONNECT DURING INSTALLING AND CONFIGURING SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/01/29/cannot-connect-to-database-master-at-sql-server-at-servername-the-database-might-not-exist-or-the-current-user-does-not-have-permission-to-connect/)
- Start installing the database server with one of the following SQL Server editions.

  - The 64-bit edition of SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1
  - The 64-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2012.
  - SQL Server 2014 with the May 2014 Cumulative Update.
- Run SharePoint Prerequisites on both App server and WFE Server.
- Install SharePoint In both but don't run the configuration wizard.
- Run the Configuration Wizard **first** on the Application server that will host the `Central Administration`.
- Then join the WFE Server to the current farm by running the Configuration Wizard on the WFE Server.

For more details check [Install SharePoint 2013 across multiple servers for a three-tier farm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805948.aspx)

Comment: Just add to this very thorough answer. You should have a look at AutoSPInstaller. It is worth learning how to use it as it will make your life much easier.